# Cryptoanalysis: Howto find the password out of several Hex-Values which are XOR encrypted with the same password?

Tags: passwords, xor

I am pretty unsure if it might be possible to find the password out of several Hex-Values which are XOR encrypted all with the same password?

For example these are some HEX values all XOR encrypted with the same HEX password which has exactly the same length as these values:

```
a0c91eab4f88c644433311f88b733655c3d03148c25b375123545d8fb3fe7ec7

b885f3cb8f529670040f3e6b15afa84a1a85ace03b108d3b410bc17747352bc3

77d147fdf263471fdfb756c436c1b86911de0a1d688997cfcabc5f6d34a6e045

464c506a68b73f4004e553b215c41ca9ec45c1200c4072ee940596e6760c2007

860a2f619063990663d3fc15d149e6baec423f40d6dd6d5c714ae373cee05985

188c1720cacc341cda9642feecfb05d89af2fe0e5e4bf560f1b85eec6a5b99e8

c3c9271bcd0a295276f9fd1bca172c4be45d3bdfc437992cfdd4a6914d03bdfa
```

Has anyone around here an idea how to solve that problem?

---

@phs and @Kerrek SB

Thanks for your response. I would really like to add an answer to your comments but unfortunately I am unable because the comment link does not work as of this JavaScript-Error as it seems. Not sure what that is all about.

> Error: `missing ) after condition`
>   Source File: http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=ea83ae356357
>   Line: 1, Column: 242
>   Source Code:
>
> ```
> comment")>-1){var i=g.attr("id").substr("comments-link-".length);var h=c(i);b(i,h,f);return true}return false};return{loadRest:d,init:a,jCommentsDiv:c,showComments:e,fetchComments:b}})();StackExchange.share=(function(){function a(d,b,c){if(!1;''.concat(d, ...
> ```

---

The ciphertext is ASCII (0 ... 254) converted into hex, the password is just a hex string same length as the ciphertext.

---

@muntoo

Many thanks for the proper formatting of my question. I really would like to know how you managed that because I am not able to see how you did it? This website is really strange in its behaviour, which is quit sad because of all the useful information. I get constantly logged out after clicking on any other message, links don't work, buttons don't work and so on ...

Cheers,
Karl-Uwe

P.S.: Still unable to post a reply to a comment, only the edit link is working as expected :-(

---

Okay than as this website does not work properly because my NoScript- and Ghostery-AddOn preventing so many foreign domains from loading some kind of weird JavaScript for this website I give up now.

The password I was searching for is 26ffe258d67de61313fc50c55b6afe5f58cbf7bd446354e02947b6c803f13d04

I suppose it's impossible to find it through cryptanalysis because it's an XOR enciphering with random HEX strings. In fact if I would encipher the same text every time with a random string it would be the same the other way round - no chance to decipher it.

Cheers and bye,
Karl-Uwe

Comment: Do you know anything about the distribution of the plaintext, cyphertext or the password?

Comment: Are all the plain-text strings ASCII?

Comment: You would need some way of knowing whether you've found the right key or not. As Kerrek asks, if the strings are ASCII, then with enough inputs you can eliminate possible passwords that would create a non-ASCII plaintext. If the plaintexts are random hex strings, then if you know something about the random generator (as phs asks), you may be able to work something out from there. More importantly, make sure your virus scanner and other security software is up to date...